# Roots less than 1 if at least one coefficient is greater than one

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebra-precalculus, complex-analysis, polynomials, roots

I have this doubt. If you have this equation with $\alpha_i \in \mathbb R$
$$P(z)=1-\alpha_{1}z-\alpha_{2}z^{2}- \cdots - \alpha_{p}z^{p}=0$$
I believe that if there exist an $\alpha$ greater or equal to one, there exist a root less or equal to one in module.
I know it is true if p is 1 or p is 2 but i don't know how to prove it in general, if it is true, of course,
In fact, i know the conditions if p=2 for not root inside the unit circle are
$$-1<\alpha_{2}<1 $$
$$\alpha_{2}-\alpha_{1}<1 $$
$$ \alpha_{2}+\alpha_{1}<1 $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your conjecture (if I understand it correctly) seems to be wrong, even for $p=2$. As an example,
$$
  P(z) = \frac{(z+ 1.5)^2}{2.25} = 1 + \frac{3}{2.25}z + \frac{1}{2.25}z^2
$$
has no root in the unit disk, but $\alpha_1 > 1$.

*Remark:* This answer applies to the initial version of the question where
the polynomial was defined as $P(z)=1+\alpha_{1}z+\alpha_{2}z^{2}+ \cdots + \alpha_{p}z^{p}$.

Comment: in this case i didnt mean in absolute value, -(3/2.25)<0 sorry i didnt explained myself correctly

Comment: @manu: I have edited the answer. $\alpha_1 = 3/2.25 > 1$ is positive.

Comment: @manu: Why did you accept the answer if it does not answer your (changed) question?